# Recuperando um json e transformando em html

Tags: javascript

Eu gostaria de saber como converto esse retorno que estou criando para HTML, ele está exibindo uma string os elemntos html estão vindo como string no navegador, segue meu código abaixo

```js
        var ul = $('<ul>').appendTo('body');
    var json = { items: httpRequest.response.headDocument};

    var counter = 1;
    $(json.items).each(function(index, item) {

     for (i = 0; i < item.content.length; i++) { 

       if (typeof item.content[i].content.bodyHtml != "undefined") {

            console.log(item.content[i].content.bodyHtml)
            console.log(i)

             ul.append(


             $(document.createElement('li')).text(item.content[i].content.bodyHtml)

           );
          }

          console.log(item.content)
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bruno, acredito que você está com duvidas recorrentes sobre o assunto, então vamos a uma abordagem.

note que o JSON que você esta trabalhando não está unificado, alguns content não possuem um Body e alguns possuem anexos.

Neste caso precisamos definir o que é util e o que não é, no exemplo abaixo estou defininfo que anexos são opcionais e conteudo sem Body será ignorado.

para montar o HTML, ao invés de fazemos isto na mão, iremos usar um template, então iremos clonar este template sempre que precisamos dele.

Note que para acessamos os elementos do template, iremos fazer uma busca por classe, sempre tendo como scopo o proprio template.

abaixo segue as informações que serão extraidas de `httpRequest.response.headDocument`:

- authors.avatar:
- authors.displayName:
- authors.profileUrl:
- content[i].content.bodyHtml:
- content[i].content.createdAt:
- content[i].content.attachments[j].thumbnail_url
- content[i].content.attachments[j].url
- content[i].content.attachments[j].title

então reduziremos para a seguinte estrutura:

- authorAvatar
- authorName
- authorUrl
- bodyHtml
- createdAt
- anexos[]

```js
var tmplConteudo = document.getElementById("tmplConteudo").content;
var tmplAnexo = document.getElementById("tmplAnexo").content;
var url = "https://client-demo-accounts-2.bootstrap.fyre.co/bs3/v3.1/client-demo-accounts-2.fyre.co/379221/MjAxNjAxMjcxMjQyOmRlc2lnbmVyLWFwcC0xNDUzODQwMjgxODk0/init";

var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open("GET", url);
httpRequest.responseType = "json";
httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (httpRequest.readyState == 4){
    if (httpRequest.status == 200){    
      var contents = httpRequest.response.headDocument.content;
      var conteudos = [];
      contents.forEach(function (content, indice) {
        var author = httpRequest.response.headDocument.authors[content.content.authorId];
        if (author && content.content.bodyHtml) {
          var conteudo = {};
          conteudo.authorAvatar = author.avatar;
          conteudo.authorName = author.displayName;
          conteudo.authorUrl = author.profileUrl;
          conteudo.bodyHtml = content.content.bodyHtml;
          conteudo.createdAt = content.content.createdAt;
          conteudo.anexos = [];
          if (content.content.attachments) {
            conteudo.anexos = content.content.attachments.map(function (attachment, indice) {
              var anexo ={}; 
              anexo.thumbnail_url = attachment.thumbnail_url;
              anexo.title = attachment.title;
              anexo.url = attachment.url;
              return anexo;          
            });
          }
          conteudos.push(conteudo);
        }
      });

      conteudos.forEach(function (conteudo, indice) {
        var node = {};
        node.fragment = document.importNode(tmplConteudo, true);
        node.container = node.fragment.querySelector(".container");
        node.avatar = node.container.querySelector(".avatar");
        node.titulo = node.container.querySelector(".titulo");
        node.conteudo = node.container.querySelector(".conteudo");
        node.rodape = node.container.querySelector(".rodape");

        node.avatar.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + conteudo.authorAvatar + "')";
        node.author = node.titulo.querySelector("a");
        node.author.href = conteudo.authorUrl;
        node.author.title = conteudo.authorName;
        node.author.textContent = conteudo.authorName;        
        node.conteudo.innerHTML = conteudo.bodyHtml;

        conteudo.anexos.forEach(function (anexo, indice) {
          var image = {};
          image.fragment = document.importNode(tmplAnexo, true);
          image.link = image.fragment.querySelector(".link");
          image.thumbnail = image.fragment.querySelector(".thumbnail");
          image.link.href = anexo.url;
          image.link.title = anexo.title;
          image.thumbnail.src = anexo.thumbnail_url;
          image.thumbnail.title = anexo.title;
          node.rodape.appendChild(image.fragment);
        });
        document.body.appendChild(node.fragment);
      });
    } else {

    }
  }
});

httpRequest.send();
```

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
  height: 180px;
}

.container div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container .avatar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;  
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 180px;
  border-right: 1px solid gainsboro;
  
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container .titulo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;  
  right: 0px;
  left: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro;
}

.container .conteudo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;  
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 180px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro;
}

.container .rodape {
  position: absolute;  
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;  
  left: 180px;
  height: 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid gainsboro;
}
```

```html
<template id="tmplConteudo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="avatar">

    </div>
    <div class="titulo">
      <a href="" title=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="conteudo"></div>
    <div class="rodape"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="tmplAnexo">
  <a class="link" href="" title="">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="" title="" />
  </a>
</template>
```

O exemplo acima não está funcionando no SO, mas você pode conferir no [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TobyMosque/xtk52m1o/1/)

Tudo que você vai precisar fazer, é adequar o seu modelo e atualizar o template. no exemplo acima usei um template um pouco mais complexo, deve ser simples alterar ele para usar uma simples li.

Comment: exelente resposta!

Answer (score 1):

É quase isso que você já tem. O código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
//Adiciona o elemento "ul" ao elemento "body".
var ul = $('<ul>').appendTo('body');
var json = { items: httpRequest.response.headDocument};

var counter = 1;
$(json.items).each(function(index, item) {
    for (i = 0; i < item.content.length; i++) { 
        if (typeof item.content[i].content.bodyHtml != "undefined") {
            //Cria o elemento "li" e o adiciona ao elemento "ul" que foi instanciado anteriormente.
            $('<li/>')
                .text(item.content[i].content.bodyHtml)
                .appendTo(ul);
        }
    }
}
```